# Javascript/HTML: Let the user change the menu name on a web site

Tags: javascript, html, menu

I am building a page with a menu selection on top or sections. I want to let the user change the name of the section. Is there a way to change the name of a html element using Javascript with right-click?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to store the changed name anywhere ?

Comment: Yes.. I need to work on the UI first then worry about the DB

Comment: Can you share some of your code ? Have you tried anything which is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, though the exact specifics depend on what you want to do. The easiest, most basic, volatile way is adding the `contenteditable` attribute:

```
<div class="section" contenteditable> ... </div>
```

Again, depending on your needs, you'll want to detect when they're changing the content of that div, maybe save it to the server or the local storage, etc etc.